# Debian/Raspbian server freezes - how to find out what is causing it?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, freeze, crash

I am using Raspbian on my RPi but few days ago it started to freeze. By freeze I mean, it is running headless server and I see line raspberry login: _ and cursors blinks. But once daily if freezes and cursor does not blink anymore.

How to find out what is causing it?

When sometimes my RPi freezed in the past (once per 6-12 months) it showed me for example journal error or some kind of meaningful error message. But now nothing, just cursor stops blinking. I am pretty helpless without any error message. And nothing is in logs, too.

Comment: Can you still login via `ssh` etc. when it freezes?

Comment: no, I must power cycle it (unplug from electricity and plug it again).

Comment: Then it will probably be pretty difficult to find the reason.

Comment: :( I was afraid of that